# How to list installed Chocolatey packages?

Tags: chocolatey

Probably a simple question, but how do I get Chocolatey to list which packages are currently installed on my system?

When googling, I end up at the question below. It is related but slightly different, and it doesn't have a simple answer to my question.

[Is there a way to list chocolatey packages with their install directory](https://superuser.com/questions/786024/is-there-a-way-to-list-chocolatey-packages-with-their-install-directory)

Comment: Packages are installed in `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib` (or in `$env:ChocolateyInstall`). See what is in there.

Answer (score 165):

```
choco list --local-only
```

Or:

```
clist -l
```

Source: https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-list

This list all packages that are currently installed on your local machine, with version numbers.

```
λ  choco list --local-only
Chocolatey v0.10.8
7zip.commandline 16.02.0.20170209
(...)
41 packages installed.
```

Comment: If this pops up another command window which then disappears, run your initial cmd/PowerShell window as Administrator.

Comment: `clist` will be deprecated in v2, and `--local-only` can also be invoked with `--localonly` or simply `-l`.

Comment: As mentioned, the `clist` is being deprecated, and further, `choco list` is changing to only list the currently installed packages, therefore, going forward, the `--local-only` option is not required. I have updated my answer below with information on the `choco export` command, which may also be useful.

Comment: It's now removed.

Answer (score 55):

**UPDATE:**

Starting with version 0.11.0 of Chocolatey CLI, there is now a `choco export` command, which allows the creation of a packages.config file, which includes a list of all the currently installed packages on teh machine.

Details on this command can be found here:

https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/export

After executing this command, and generating the file, you can then do the following on another machine, which would allow on packages to be installed there:

```
choco install <path_to_generated_file>
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Another alternative would be to install the official Chocolatey GUI application.  This includes a tab which shows all the currently installed applications in your machine.

To install it, simply do:

`choco install chocolateygui`

The GitHub Repository for Chocolatey GUI can be found here:

https://github.com/chocolatey/ChocolateyGUI

And a screenshot of the UI can be seen here:

[image: Chocolatey GUI Application Loaded]

Comment: I like it. Thank you.
Most common operations are easy to remember for cmd.
Less frequent cases to solve with GUI :).

Answer (score 6):

On Windows 10, [PowerShell](https://microsoft.com/PowerShell) 7.3.8 through [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) 1.18:

```shell
> clist -l
clist: The term 'clist' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

> choco list --local-only
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Invalid argument --local-only. This argument has been removed from the list command and cannot be used.

> choco list --localonly
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Invalid argument --localonly. This argument has been removed from the list command and cannot be used.

> choco list
Chocolatey v2.2.2
chocolatey 2.2.2
chocolatey-compatibility.extension 1.0.0
chocolatey-core.extension 1.4.0
chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension 1.0.4
composer 6.3.0
nodejs-lts 18.17.1
nuget.commandline 6.5.0
php 8.2.9
python 3.11.5
python312 3.12.0-a6
tinytex 2023.8.0
vcredist140 14.32.31326
vcredist2015 14.0.24215.20170201
yarn 1.22.19
24 packages installed.
```

So, `choco list` does the job on my system.